# Difference between "\n" and Environment.NewLine

Tags: c#, .net, cross-platform

What is the difference between two, if any (with respect to .Net)?

Answer (score 233, accepted):

Depends on the platform. On Windows it is actually "\r\n".

From MSDN:

> A string containing "\r\n" for
>   non-Unix platforms, or a string
>   containing "\n" for Unix platforms.

Comment: Which UNIX platform does .NET run to Microsoft put into its doc? (I mean, a part from Mono.)

Comment: @Jack You could be writing to a file that will be opened in Unix platform. Or sending text in package that will be received by a unix platform. And in a few months .net will be running on Unix platforms. It already has begun

Comment: So just for clarity: on a non-Unix platform `Environment.NewLine` is `\r\n` but `\n` is also called "new line".  Why didn't they just call the latter by its more well-known name "line feed" and cut out the confusion?  They could have used `\l` also.

Answer (score 177):

Exact implementation of `Environment.NewLine` from the source code:

The implementation in .NET 4.6.1:

```
/*===================================NewLine====================================
**Action: A property which returns the appropriate newline string for the given
**        platform.
**Returns: \r\n on Win32.
**Arguments: None.
**Exceptions: None.
==============================================================================*/
public static String NewLine {
    get {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<String>() != null);
        return "\r\n";
    }
}
```

[source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/environment.cs#63a04833d43dd9d3)

---

The implementation in .NET Core:

```
/*===================================NewLine====================================
**Action: A property which returns the appropriate newline string for the
**        given platform.
**Returns: \r\n on Win32.
**Arguments: None.
**Exceptions: None.
==============================================================================*/
public static String NewLine {
    get {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result() != null);
#if !PLATFORM_UNIX
        return "\r\n";
#else
        return "\n";
#endif // !PLATFORM_UNIX
    }
}
```

[source](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Environment.cs,63a04833d43dd9d3) (in `System.Private.CoreLib`)

```
public static string NewLine => "\r\n";
```

[source](https://source.dot.net/#System.Runtime.Extensions/System/Environment.Windows.cs,63a04833d43dd9d3) (in `System.Runtime.Extensions`)

Comment: yeah :) For some reason I was expecting the .NET implementation to be some huge complicated function

Comment: Considering the simplicity of the source in this instance, it probably should be the answer.

Answer (score 70):

As others have mentioned, `Environment.NewLine` returns a platform-specific string for beginning a new line, which should be:

- `"\r\n"` (\u000D\u000A) for Windows
- `"\n"` (\u000A) for Unix
- `"\r"` (\u000D) for Mac (if such implementation existed)

Note that when writing to the console, Environment.NewLine is not strictly necessary.  The console stream will translate `"\n"` to the appropriate new-line sequence, if necessary.

Comment: The Mac implementation does exist. Just Mono. Runs on anything.

Comment: Just a note, that would be old macs; new (OSX) macs use `\n`

Comment: @Dykam, yeah but it runs real slow-like on my HP48gx

Comment: @cod3monk3y: That's fast compared to my HP48sx!

Comment: As others have mentioned and as is visible in the .Net source also attached to this question, this answer is not correct.

Comment: @ChrisWalter this answer could be correct back in 2009. Today, it is outdated.

Comment: @aloisdg 2009? Apple hasn't used CR for 17 years; not since the initial release of macOS. This "non-Unix" thing is misleading. Windows is the only relevant OS that doesn't use LF. Linux, macOS, the BSDs, BeOS, RISC OS, and many more all use LFs.

Comment: @Blieque just saying that it might have been true in 2009, not that it was. I didnt check.

Answer (score 27):

`Environment.NewLine` will return the newline character for the corresponding platform in which your code is running

you will find this very useful when you deploy your code in linux on the [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) framework

Answer (score 8):

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) ...

> A string containing "\r\n" for
>   non-Unix platforms,  or  a string
>   containing "\n" for Unix platforms.

Answer (score 5):

You might get into trouble when you try to display multi-line message separated with "\r\n".

It is always a good practice to do things in a standard way, and use Environment.NewLine

Answer (score 4):

Environment.NewLine will give "\r\n" when run on Windows.  If you are generating strings for Unix based environments, you don't want the "\r".