# Is \n equivalent to Environment.NewLine in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, newline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between “\n” and Environment.NewLine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015766/difference-between-n-and-environment-newline)

Hello all!

The way I understand it, when we use `.` symbol in format string for double, it doesn't mean "dot", it actually means "decimal separator used in current environment", so if we are working with non-US culture settings, the output can be `2,00` instead of `2.00`. That's quite handy.

Now, is it also true for `\n` (LF) special symbol? Will it become `System.Environment.NewLine` symbol when the format string gets parsed or will it always be `0x0A` value regardless of system settings? `Environment.NewLine` is kinda wordy and I wonder if I can just use `\n` safely instead.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @jayrdub: yes, I know that, but that's exactly what I'm asking - whether `\n` means "\n" or "whatever endline symbols used in current environment"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is may be your answer [Difference between "\n" and Environment.NewLine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015766/difference-between-n-and-environment-newline)

Comment: Thanks, one of the answer there partially suits my question as well

Answer (score 2):

The point of using it is for portability between OSs

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx

> A string containing "\r\n" for
>   non-Unix platforms, or a string
>   containing "\n" for Unix platforms.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like typing out `System.Environment.NewLine` set a local var to that value.

```
string n = System.Environment.NewLine;
string stringWithStuff = "text!" + n + "moretext!";
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with doing it this way.

Comment: It depends on the context, really

Comment: @sehe What's wrong with that? You're not suggesting using a StringBuilder for that, are you?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably aware that text writers have a `NewLine` property too

i.e.

```
using System;

//  ...
Console.Write("eenie{0}meenie{0}minie{0}moe", Console.NewLine);
Console.Out.Write("eenie{0}meenie{0}minie{0}moe", Console.Out.NewLine);
Console.Error.Write("eenie{0}meenie{0}minie{0}moe", Console.Error.NewLine);
```

I'm not too sure from the top of my head whether that would always by definition be the same as `System.Environment.NewLine`. Cf. the docs

Answer (score 0):

Refering to [Environment.NewLine Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx):

> A string containing "\r\n" for
>   non-Unix platforms, or a string
>   containing "\n" for Unix platforms.

Also:

> The property value of NewLine is a
>   constant customized specifically for
>   the current platform and
>   implementation of the .NET Framework.
>
> NewLine can be used in conjunction
>   with language-specific newline support
>   such as the escape characters '\r' and
>   '\n' in Microsoft C# and C/C++, or
>   vbCrLf in Microsoft Visual Basic.