# From DataGridView to multiline commaSeparated string

Tags: c#, winforms, string, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with four Columns and need to crate a multiline string from its content, separated by comma.
This code works, but probably - there is a more elegant way:

```
string multiLine = "";
string singleLine;    
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgvSm.Rows)
{
    if (!r.IsNewRow)
    {
        singleLine = r.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + ","
        + r.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + ","
        + r.Cells[2].Value.ToString() + ","
        + r.Cells[3].Value.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
        multiLine = multiLine + singleLine;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about *elegant*, but:

1. **use StringBuilder** for string manipulation, type string is immutable!
2. if you need to do something in between, separate first or last cycle running (e.g. comma separation)
   So, basically something like this:

```
StringBuilder multiLine = new StringBuilder();
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgvSm.Rows)
{
 if (!r.IsNewRow)
 {
  if (r.Cells.Count > 0)
  {
   multiLine.Append(r.Cells[0].Value.ToString()); //first separated
   for (int i = 1; i < r.Cells.Count; ++i)
   {
    singleLine.Append(','); //between values
    singleLine.Append(r.Cells[i].Value.ToString());
   }
   multiLine.AppendLine();
  }
 }
}
```

To illustrate speed difference between StringBuilder concatenation (just dynamic array of characters) and string (new object and copy everything each time you use operator + concatenation), have a look at mini-program:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    //string s = "";
    int i;
    for (i = 0; sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < 1000; ++i)
        //s += i.ToString();
        s.Append(i.ToString());
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("using version with type " + s.GetType().Name + " I did " +
        i + " times of string concatenation.");
}
```

For my computer it is:

```
using version with type String I did 17682 times of string concatenation.
using version with type StringBuilder I did 366367 times of string concatenation.
```

Comment: peenut, maybe your code takes more processing time than the first one (if a dgv has 1000 rows, for example. What do you think?

Comment: Buena, I added code to compare string and StringBuilder speed

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    string multiLine = "";
string singleLine;    
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgvSm.Rows)
{
if (!r.IsNewRow)
{
singleLine = r.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + ","
+ r.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + ","
+ r.Cells[2].Value.ToString() + ","
+ r.Cells[3].Value.ToString() + "\r\n";
multiLine = multiLine + singleLine;
}
}
```

Comment: aliboy, is there another difference between "Environment.NewLine" and "\r\n" except the number of characters?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015766/difference-between-n-and-environment-newline

Comment: ThankYou, Elisa. Useful for me.