# XML reader, export data into a file C# Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, visual-studio-2012, export

I have this Windows form, that inside a button I call a API and I get the information requested. This works very well but I am looking for its when I request the data, I would like to be able to export it into a xml file or to a CSV file.
There's a way to achieve this?, here yo have my code.

Thanks

```
proxy.Dashboard pr = new proxy.Dashboard();
pr.APIKeyValue = new proxy.APIKeyHeader(); 
pr.APIKeyValue.Value = "25478-69874-fde44-ertyy";
proxy.ProjectData[] nc = pr.GetAllProjectData();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (proxy.ProjectData som in nc) 
{ 
    sb.AppendLine("\r\n");  
    sb.AppendLine("\r\n" + som.ProjectTitle + " " + som.ProjectID + " " + som.PublishStatus); 
}

label1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: there are tons of resources on how to export to a xml or csv file. google it.

Comment: Hi, I been trying to look every where but I had to success that's why I posted the question here. Thanks a lot

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757097/writing-data-into-csv-file

Comment: Linq to XML / XMLwritter / xml serialization... good luck

Comment: Thanks @DLeh I got the answer over there. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to export to XML add "using System.xml" then loop through your data as follow.

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("GiveNameToYourFile.xml"))
{
    writer.WriteStartDocument();
    writer.WriteStartElement("GiveTagNameToYourDocument");

    foreach (proxy.ProjectData som in nc)
    {
    writer.WriteStartElement("GiveNameToYourElement");

    writer.WriteElementString("ProjectTitle", som.ProjectTitle);
    writer.WriteElementString("ProjectID", som.ProjectID);
    writer.WriteElementString("PublishStatus", som.PublishStatus);

    writer.WriteEndElement();
    }

    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndDocument();
}
```

If you want to export to excel go to http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/692121/Csharp-Export-data-to-Excel-using-OpenXML-librarie very useful helps you export your data to excel using OpenXML Library.
Hopefully this help you. Good Luck

Comment: You're most welcome. please vote for the answer if it was helpful and useful. Thanks