# Sharepoint 2013 workflow write to csv file

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-2013

I am working on a project. I got this sharepoint list and i want to create a workflow which write to an csv file every time i delete a item in the list.

Is this possible and how? :)

Thanks :)

Comment: Please select the answer below if it answers this question, or leave a comment on it.

Answer (score 0):

**No. It is not possible via SharePoint Workflow.**

However, you can achieve it via SharePoint List Item event handler.

1. Create a [ItemDeleting](http://onceinawhilescribble.blogspot.in/2013/05/creating-simple-event-receiver-in.html) event handler for the list.
2. A web service to handle the [csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757097/writing-data-into-csv-file) related operation like file creation/content modification and call it under the ItemDeleting event.