# Creating a .csv file for my esurvey application. How do I start? (Duplicate)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, csv, visual-studio-2013

I'm having trouble with coding my Esurvey application(using Windows Store C# XAML) and I really need help. I need to create a .csv database which contains all results(radiobutton selections and text inputs) but I'm not sure where to even start.

Can someone help me with this? I'm using Visual Studio Community 2013.

```
using FYPPrototype1.Common;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Text;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Windows.UI.Popups;

// The Basic Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234237

namespace FYPPrototype1
{
/// <summary>
/// A basic page that provides characteristics common to most applications.
/// </summary>
/// 


public sealed partial class SurveyPage1 : Page
{

    private NavigationHelper navigationHelper;
    private ObservableDictionary defaultViewModel = new ObservableDictionary();

    /// <summary>
    /// This can be changed to a strongly typed view model.
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableDictionary DefaultViewModel
    {
        get { return this.defaultViewModel; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// NavigationHelper is used on each page to aid in navigation and 
    /// process lifetime management
    /// </summary>
    public NavigationHelper NavigationHelper
    {
        get { return this.navigationHelper; }
    }


    public SurveyPage1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
        this.navigationHelper.LoadState += navigationHelper_LoadState;
        this.navigationHelper.SaveState += navigationHelper_SaveState;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Populates the page with content passed during navigation. Any saved state is also
    /// provided when recreating a page from a prior session.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">
    /// The source of the event; typically <see cref="NavigationHelper"/>
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="e">Event data that provides both the navigation parameter passed to
    /// <see cref="Frame.Navigate(Type, Object)"/> when this page was initially requested and
    /// a dictionary of state preserved by this page during an earlier
    /// session. The state will be null the first time a page is visited.</param>
    private void navigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PageState != null && e.PageState.ContainsKey("rbNumber1") && e.PageState.ContainsKey("rbNumber2") && e.PageState.ContainsKey("rbNumber3") && e.PageState.ContainsKey("rbNumber4"))
        {
            radioExcellent.IsChecked = (bool)e.PageState["rbNumber1"];
            radioGood.IsChecked = (bool)e.PageState["rbNumber2"];
            radioPoor.IsChecked = (bool)e.PageState["rbNumber3"];
            radioAverage.IsChecked = (bool)e.PageState["rbNumber4"];
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Preserves state associated with this page in case the application is suspended or the
    /// page is discarded from the navigation cache.  Values must conform to the serialization
    /// requirements of <see cref="SuspensionManager.SessionState"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event; typically <see cref="NavigationHelper"/></param>
    /// <param name="e">Event data that provides an empty dictionary to be populated with
    /// serializable state.</param>
    private void navigationHelper_SaveState(object sender, SaveStateEventArgs e)
    {
        e.PageState["rbNumber1"] = radioExcellent.IsChecked;
        e.PageState["rbNumber2"] = radioGood.IsChecked;
        e.PageState["rbNumber3"] = radioPoor.IsChecked;
        e.PageState["rbNumber4"] = radioAverage.IsChecked;
    }

    #region NavigationHelper registration

    /// The methods provided in this section are simply used to allow
    /// NavigationHelper to respond to the page's navigation methods.
    /// 
    /// Page specific logic should be placed in event handlers for the  
    /// <see cref="GridCS.Common.NavigationHelper.LoadState"/>
    /// and <see cref="GridCS.Common.NavigationHelper.SaveState"/>.
    /// The navigation parameter is available in the LoadState method 
    /// in addition to page state preserved during an earlier session.

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        navigationHelper.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
    }

    #endregion

    private async void Button_S1_S2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (radioExcellent.IsChecked != true && radioGood.IsChecked != true && radioAverage.IsChecked != true && radioPoor.IsChecked != true)
        {
            MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog("Please select an option before proceeding!");
            await md.ShowAsync();
        }

        else
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SurveyPage2));
        }
    }
}
}
```

[image: Here is a screenshot of my application in case you need a reference.]

Here is a screenshot of my application in case you need a reference.

[image]

This is the output that my teacher wants but I have no idea how to make it as shown :(