# Log files from Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have create a project in Unity3d. I have inside the scipt code several print methods that print information during execution of the unity. I want to parse that information to log files since I want to create a build version of my Unity project. How can I perform so?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking. If you use Debug.Log you will already have an output log file you can use. If that doesn't suffice, what exactly are you trying to achieve, and how far have you gotten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if related or not, but read this: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html.

You can also write to a text file, XML file, CSV file or even database. It just depends. Do some Googling on C#.

Writing to text file:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa735748(VS.71).aspx

Writing to CSV:
[Writing data into CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757097/writing-data-into-csv-file)

Comment: This is a borderline link-only answer. You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.