# Writing contents of a class to a file

Tags: c#

I have a `class`, all string properties like this:

```
public class MyClass 
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string Phone {get;set;}
  // a bunch of more fields....
{
```

And a list of that class `List<MyClass>  myListOfObjects`;   that I have populated it through out the program with values.

And then I have a `file (csv)`  with headers:

```
Name, Phone, etc...
```

I want to write the contents of that `myListOfObjects` into that file.
I was thinking just loop through them and write one row per object. But wanted to see is there a better nicer way?

Comment: you could override `ToString()` for your class to make it easier, but looping through and writing per object is pretty much it.

Comment: Did you want to write all properties to a file, or just a select few?

Comment: @DanielGimenez  all except one!

Comment: Have you [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757097/writing-data-into-csv-file)?

Comment: @Bohn: If you'll be in Lambeau Sunday, paint "Bohn" on your cheesehead and I'll look for you (on tv).

Answer (score 2):

You can write all your data in one shot, like

```
var list = new List<MyClass>();
var fileData = list.Select(row => string.Join(",", row.Name, row.Phone, row.Etc)).ToArray();

File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\YourFile", fileData);
```

**Note:** This is one way to improve the file write, but it doesn't handle un-escaped text data like Name with comma.

Comment: Not really a good solution, though could be if you also handle text qualifiers and string escaping.  This will fail if there is a common in Name for example.

Comment: @DanielGimenez that's true. From the question it seems like he has already handled that, and he is looking for a "better" way than looping through each object and write to file for each. This was just to give a hint towards improving that, not handling un-escaped text data.