# How to export Event Viewer logs to csv using C#

Tags: c#, export-to-csv, event-viewer

We are looking into writing a C# program which will export Event Viewer logs into csv file.

```
DateTime              |Level    | Source | EventID | Detail
06/16/2016 10:11:01    Error       ABC      100      Detail of event error
```

Can you please guide/hint if you knows anything which suits for this?
Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This application exists of two parts.
1. Reading the eventlog
2. Writing to a csv file

Reading the eventlog is built in to .NET. Examples can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6b9a7h8(v=vs.100).aspx). The application might need administrator rights to do this.

For writing to a csv file you can use the .net file and stringbuilder classes.
In a csv file each line is a row and columns are split by a comma.
This is already discussed in an other question: [Writing data into CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757097/writing-data-into-csv-file)

Comment: It helped, Maiko. Thank you! :)