# C# write to csv file

Tags: c#, arrays, csv, datatable

I want to dynamically format any column's date to `yyyy-MM-dd`. I know i can conditionally set a specific column to this date format, but **is there any way to do it dynamically for all columns that have dates**. Currently I am using a `try catch` here which works for all dates, but the problem is that any columns that aren't dates i.e. a value of **3.8707** will become `01/03/8707` on the csv output

```
foreach (var array in from DataRow myrow in dt.Rows select row.ItemArray)
{
    for (i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        try
        {
             DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(array[i].ToString());
             swOut.Write(date.Year + '-' + date.Month + '-' + date.Day + ",");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
             swOut.Write(array[i] + ",");
        }
     }
     swOut.WriteLine();                 
}
```

Comment: is the date format always the same dd/mm/yyy ? or does it differ between the entries in the array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing data into CSV file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757097/writing-data-into-csv-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18465222/1016343)** and copy the static class **`Extensions`** with the **extension method `toDate(...)` I have written** (don't forget to add `using System.Globalization;`).
If you're using it, you can do it simply like this, without having to catch an exception:

```
var arrayItems = from DataRow myrow in dt.Rows select row.ItemArray;
foreach (var array in arrayItems)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {           
        var strItem = (array[i] ?? "").ToString();
        var date=strItem.toDate("yyyy-MM-dd");
        if (!date.HasValue) {
            swOut.Write(strItem + ",");
        }
        else
        {
            swOut.Write(date.Value.Year + '-' + 
                            date.Value.Month + '-' + date.Value.Day + ",");
        }
    }
    swOut.WriteLine();
}
```

**Note that** if you have to match a different data format, just change the parameter in the funtion `.toDate("yyyy-MM-dd")`. You can even specify multiple data formats which are accepted, like so:

```
string[] dateFmt = {"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", "M/d/yyyy h:mm tt", 
                 "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss", 
                 "M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt", "M/d/yyyy hh tt", 
                 "M/d/yyyy h:mm", "M/d/yyyy h:mm", 
                 "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm", "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm"};
```

then inside the loop you can use it:

```
var date=strItem.toDate(dateFmt);
```

That way, they will be interpreted and parsed and then they will be converted into `YYYY-MM-dd` and written into the `.csv` file, as you have specified it in the `Write` statement of your `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks for that Matt. but toDate cannot be resolved. the static class your using

Comment: @A.Dal:  Please read the beginning of my answer - **[click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366285/parse-string-to-datetime-in-c-sharp/18465222#18465222)** and then copy it. This static class was written by me.

Comment: @A.Dal - with the hints I gave, could you fix it?

Comment: @A.Dal -You're welcome, glad to hear it is working! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making your own datetime format parser, you should use the one already available for you. DateTime.TryParseExact is your tool to convert a string in a date when you know the exact format. If you know in which format the date is present in the CSV, then Converting back the date, in the string format that you like, is another task easily solved by the override of ToString() specific for a datetime.

In your code, you are using try catch that will decrease the performance.

```
string[] values = lines1[i].Split(',');
if (values.Length >= 3)
{
    DateTime dt;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(values[0], "d-MMM-yyyy", 
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
        System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
    {
        values[0] = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        lines1[i] = String.Join(",", values);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check the type of the column. Like this:

```
if(array[i] is DateTime)
{
    var date=(DateTime)array[i];
    swOut.Write(date.Year + '-' + date.Month + '-' + date.Day + ",");
}
else
    swOut.Write(array[i] + ",");
```