# get mongodb table into datatable

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have collection in MongoDB , what i want to do is to retrieve data in the cassandra , and export it into a csv file .
what i want is to transform each row into a , comma seperated string and insert it each time in the csv file , i started to collect the data in the collection , any help fir the rest , am new to c#, lany thanks

```
        var server = MongoServer.Create("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        var DB = server.GetDatabase("shop");
        var collection = DB.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Mobiles");
        var list = collection.FindAll();

        foreach (var dox in list)
        {
            insert into the csv file 
        }
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: SEE: [Writing data into CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757097/writing-data-into-csv-file)

Comment: @MadMyche , the problem is not with writing data into csv , but i need help with geting columbs in a bson document and insert it into line in csv file Thanks