# Writing and Reading excel files in C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, selenium-webdriver, ms-office

I am writing a program that takes data from a website via selenium web driver. I am trying to create football fixture for our projects.
I am so far, I accomplished to take **date and time, team names and scores** from the website. Also still trying writing on txt file, but it gets little messy while writing on txt file

How do I accomplish writing on excel file, and reading?
I want to write like that

```
Date-Time     First-Team   Second-Team    Score    Statistics
28/07 19:00   AM           AVB            2-1      Shot 13123 Pass 65465 ...
28/07 20:00   BM           BVB            2-2      Shot 13123 Pass 65465 ...
28/07 20:00   CM           CVB            2-3      Shot 13123 Pass 65465 ...
```

And this is my part of my code :

```
StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\Test" + "\\" + pathName + "\\" + subFile + "\\" + pathName + ".txt", false);

for (int k = 2; k > 1; k--)
{ 
     //doing some stuff
}
```

Writing part:

```
for (int x = 0; x <dT.Count; x++)
{
     file.Write(dateTime[x] + " " + firstTeam[x] + " "
                       + secondTeam[x] + " " + firstHalf[x] + " " + secondHalf[x] + " ")
     for (int i = 0; i < total_FS.Count(); i++)
     {
           int index = total_FS[i].Length;
           if (total_FS[i][index-1].ToString() != " " && total_FS[i] != "-")
           {
                 file.Write(total_FS[i]);
           }
           else
           {
                 SpaceC++;
                 if (total_FS[i][index - 1].ToString() == " ")
                 file.Write(total_FS[i]);
           }
           if (SpaceC == 9)
           {
                 file.Write("\n");
                 SpaceC = 0;
                 break;
           }
      }


}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are few cool libraries that you can use to easy read and write excel files. You can reference them in your project and easily create/modify spreadsheets.

**EPPlus**
Very developer friendly and easy to use.

- [EPPlus - codeplex source](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)
- [Simple tutorial](http://zeeshanumardotnet.blogspot.com/2011/06/creating-reports-in-excel-2007-using.html)

**NOPI**

- [NOPI - codeplex source](http://npoi.codeplex.com/)

**DocumentFormat.OpenXml** 
It provides strongly typed classes for spreadsheet objects and seems to be fairly easy to work with.

- [DocumentFormat.OpenXml site](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml)
- [DocumentFormat.OpenXml tutorial](http://www.dispatchertimer.com/tutorial/how-to-create-an-excel-file-in-net-using-openxml-part-1-basics/)

**Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office**
Provides strongly typed classes / easy to work with.

- [Open XML SDK 2.0 - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854(office.14).aspx)

**ClosedXML - The easy way to OpenXML**
ClosedXML makes it easier for developers to create (.xlsx, .xlsm, etc) files.

- [ClosedXML - repository hosted at GitHub](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml)
- [ClosedXML - codeplex source](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/)

**SpreadsheetGear**
*Paid - library to import / export Excel workbooks in ASP.NET

- [SpreadsheetGear site](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/)

Comment: As soon as possible, I will look at it and try it. Thank you very much

Comment: I highly recommend EPPlus

Comment: @Kevin yes me too! EPPlus is nice and very easy to use.

Comment: thank you very much. I tried it. It is very easy to use.

Comment: The MS COM objects have been deprecated for years. You are supposed to use the [Open XML SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml) to work with the modern office file formats.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of creating XLS file, make a CSV text file that can be opened with Excel. Fields are comma separated and each line represents a record.

```
field11,field12
field21,field22
```

If a field contains inner commas, it needs to be wrapped in double quotation marks.

```
"field11(row1,column1)", field12
field21, field22
```

If a field contains double quotation marks, they need to be escaped. But you can use [CsvHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper) to do the job. Grab it from Nuget

> PM> Install-Package CsvHelper

An example on how to use it.

```
using(var textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\mypath\myfile.csv")
{
    var writer = new CsvWriter(textWriter);
    writer.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";

    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        csv.WriteField("field11");
        csv.WriteField("field12");
        csv.NextRecord();
    }
}
```

Full documentation can be found [here](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/).

Comment: Can't it be hard if I have lots of data. For example if I had 1,000 Team names, date-time @derloopkat

Comment: In that case you can iterate through rows first and for each row iterate through columns. Otherwise according to some code samples you can pass complex object representing a collection of rows and write them directly to the file with `writer.WriteRecords(rows);` However I haven't tried that. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44728910/2516718

Comment: Okay, I will try that. Thank you very much @derlookat