# Script to add columns and rows to a csv file?

Tags: c#, csv

Ok, to cut a long story short I am doing load testing so I need to add 1000+ user credentials (email, password) to the `DB`.  I have been using automated scripts using `selenium` and `c#` and would like to write a script to write this data into a `csv` file.  I have random generators where I can make every email unique.  I guess I would need a for loop for this? Anyone got the code for this? Btw once I have the `csv` file I already have a query to import the `csv` file into the `DB`.

So I found a script to add 2 columns but I am a total beginner so I haven't got a clue what to try, all google searches doesn't quite do what I am after even though the job should be quite simple.

```
public static void WriteToExcelMethod(string email, string passwd)
{
    string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.csv";
    string line = String.Format(@"""{0}"",""{1}"", email, passwd);
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Is this a better script to write 2 columns and 1000 rows:

```
//before your loop
    var csv = new StringBuilder();

//in your loop
    var first = reader[0].ToString();
    var second = image.ToString();
    //Suggestion made by KyleMit
    var newLine = string.Format("{0},{1}", first, second);
    csv.AppendLine(newLine);  

//after your loop
```

Comment: Selenium is going to make a poor load tester. You'd be much better off just sending HTTP requests to your web server

Comment: Liam please dismiss the load testing I am using JMeter, please focus on my problem of writing to a csv file using selenium or c#. Your deviating I just wanted to give some background as to why I need this csv file.  Thanks

Comment: If it's not relevant why did you put it into the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing data into CSV file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757097/writing-data-into-csv-file-in-c-sharp)

Comment: What does your data source look like? For instance, a `DataTable` with 2 columns Email and Password or an array of objects? How do you "loop" through them?

Comment: Guys I am sorry for writing an overkill explanation.  All I need is to write to a csv file on windows 10 using my automated script selenium(may not be necessary) and c# within Visual Studio 2017.  The csv file is in my project with a header for the two columns

Comment: The code posted reader then entire csv file into the StreamWriter and then adds one line.  It does nothing to add any columns.  Do you need to add the file to the db before adding new columns?

Comment: jdweng no I do not need to add new columns before adding to db because once I have the csv file I have a query to update the db table from the info from the csv file so I just need this physical csv file

Comment: Guys can you please help me?  Its a simple task really just need the code