# Converting store procedure data to a csv. I am trying to figure out how to use the commas and quotations for the fields that are empty

Tags: c#, csv

```
sb.AppendLine("Employee Id,First Name,Last Name,Email,Username,Password,Role,Group Name,Country Code, Supervisor Id, Hire Date, Birth Date");

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    String[] empid = dt.Rows[i]["EmpId"].ToString().Split(new Char[] { '-' });
    sb.AppendLine(Convert.ToInt32(empid[0]).ToString("000000") + "," + dt.Rows[i]["FirstName"] + "," + dt.Rows[i]["LastName"].ToString().Replace(",", " ") +
         ",," + dt.Rows[i]["Email"] + ",reward," + dt.Rows[i]["Role"] + ",CCCC," + ",," + ",," + dt.Rows[i]["EmployeeHireDate"] + "," + dt.Rows[i]["EmployeeBirthDate"]);
}
```

email field needs to be empty,
username needs to be the email,
country code needs to be empty,
supervisor id needs to be empty,

Comment: What have you tried so far? What's your question? This is not a coding service. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Comment: needs to know how use use the quotes and comas for the empty fields. sorry new at c#

Comment: reading or writing csv - use csvhelper library

Comment: "", is enough for empty string or just a comma. "John", , "Doe" is a sample for 3 fields.

Comment: for a csv file they have to be separated by a comma so i guess "," would work for all of them that need to be empty?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing data into CSV file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757097/writing-data-into-csv-file-in-c-sharp) Use a proper library, don't do this yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this segement:

```
+ ",CCCC," + ",," + ",," +
```

with this:

```
+ ",CCCC,,," +
```

But you'll really do **MUCH** better with a dedicated csv library, of which there are several good options on NuGet.

Additionally, if you're using `StringBuilder` because you heard it's faster, remember that faster is relative. `StringBuilder` is faster than string concatenation for this kind of work, but if you're ultimately going to writing to a network stream, file, or web response you'll do even better using a `StreamWriter`

Comment: okay. I get that part but the part ___ToString().Replace(",", " ") + ",," + dt____  after the plus sign ",," does it need 2 commas or just one to represent the one space

Comment: @Dramian You want two commas there: one to end the `LastName` field, which hasn't been closed yet, and one to end the `Email` field that comes after, because you want it to be blank.