# how to save Event logs into csv file

Tags: c#, .net, logfile, event-viewer

I'm trying to save the result of log files that I get from Event viewer into a csv file and make sure its not duplicated

any suggestions please

this my code for reading the log file

```
    using System;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       
        System.Diagnostics.EventLog log = new
        System.Diagnostics.EventLog("System");


        foreach (System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntry entry in log.Entries)
        {


            {
                Console.WriteLine("Index:" + entry.Index);
                Console.WriteLine("source:"+entry.Source);
                Console.WriteLine("Level:"+entry.EntryType);
                Console.WriteLine("Event ID:"+entry.EventID);
                Console.WriteLine("TimeGenerated:"+entry.TimeGenerated);
                Console.WriteLine("User Name:"+entry.UserName);
                Console.WriteLine("Message:"+entry.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("--------");
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem is that you can't save to a csv file or that there are duplicates?

Comment: @Patrick i want to save it into csv and make sure no duplicated will happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save your logs to a csv you can follow this answer: [Writing data into CSV file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757097/writing-data-into-csv-file-in-c-sharp)

In your case it should look something like this:

```
var log = new EventLog("System");
var csv = new StringBuilder();
foreach (EventLogEntry entry in log.Entries)
{
    csv.AppendLine($"{entry.Index};{entry.Source};{entry.EntryType};{entry.EntryType};{entry.TimeGenerated};{entry.UserName};{entry.Message}");
}
File.WriteAllText("test.csv", csv.ToString());
```

It can be that you ne "," instead of ";" to make it readable for excel for example.

But I still not get what you mean by it should not print duplicates. Each line has a different event id and timestamp, so even if the message is there multiple times, there are different instances.

Comment: the code work good without error but the file still empty

Comment: Did you also find the file? It is saved in the debug folder, you can also have another file path there like "C:/test.csv". It worked for me and wrote alle the logs into the file.

Comment: last question is there anyway to separate events from each other on the file to make it readable

Comment: I have similar requirement to read evtx file and convert to csv, I tried above code and it does'nt work for me

Answer (score 0):

I have attached the screenprint for tried sample code in online
[image]