# C# Environment.Newline does not work when saving/copying to text file

Tags: c#

I am making a C# application in which I copy text from a Rich TextBox using

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(richTextBox1.Text))
        {
            Clipboard.SetText(richTextBox1.Text);

        }
```

I set the Rich TextBox code as follows

```
richTextBox1.Text = file + Environment.NewLine + r + Environment.NewLine + r1 + Environment.NewLine + r2 + Environment.NewLine + r3 + Environment.NewLine + r4 + Environment.NewLine + r5 + Environment.NewLine + r6 + Environment.NewLine + r7 + Environment.NewLine + r8 + Environment.NewLine + r9 + Environment.NewLine + r10 + Environment.NewLine + r11 + Environment.NewLine + r12 + Environment.NewLine + r13;
```

Also, I save the Rich TextBox text to a .txt file using

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(richTextBox1.Text))
         { SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Text File|*.txt";
            saveFileDialog1.Title = "Export EXIF Data";

            //  saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
           DialogResult save =  saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (save == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if (saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")
                {

                    File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, richTextBox1.Text);
                }

            }
```

Now the problem I am facing is that in the Rich TextBox, the text appears line by line where ever I have used Environment.NewLine
for e.g

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

but after copying/saving, the .txt file appears like

```
line 1line 2line 3
```

Also, if I copy the text using KeyBoard shortuct Ctrl+C , the text appears fine in the text file.

I hope you understood my problem and would be able to help me.
I can provide any more details if needed.

**Update:**
I was able to fix the problem while saving the richTextBox text to a .txt file by using string[] instead of string like:

**New Code:**

```
 data = new String[] { file, r, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, r10, r11, r12, r13 };
                 richTextBox1.Text = data[0] + Environment.NewLine + data[1] + Environment.NewLine + data[2] + Environment.NewLine + data[3] + Environment.NewLine + data[4] + Environment.NewLine + data[5] + Environment.NewLine + data[6] + Environment.NewLine + data[7] + Environment.NewLine + data[8] + Environment.NewLine + data[9] + Environment.NewLine + data[10] + Environment.NewLine + data[11] + Environment.NewLine + data[12] + Environment.NewLine + data[13] + Environment.NewLine + data[14];
//Saving:
File.WriteAllLines(saveFileDialog1.FileName, data);
```

**Old Code:**

```
richTextBox1.Text = file + Environment.NewLine + r + Environment.NewLine + r1 + Environment.NewLine + r2 + Environment.NewLine + r3 + Environment.NewLine + r4 + Environment.NewLine + r5 + Environment.NewLine + r6 + Environment.NewLine + r7 + Environment.NewLine + r8 + Environment.NewLine + r9 + Environment.NewLine + r10 + Environment.NewLine + r11 + Environment.NewLine + r12 + Environment.NewLine + r13;
//Saving:
File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, richTextBox1.Text);
```

But still the copying is not working correctly

Comment: What do you mean by "the .txt file appears like" - how are you checking it? Have you looked at it in a binary file editor to see what the actual bytes are?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the save dialog or WriteAllText? It seems that richTextBox1.Text is not what you expect. Why are you using a rich text box for unformatted text?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between "\n" and Environment.NewLine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015766/difference-between-n-and-environment-newline)

Comment: I am able to copy and save the text from the richTextbox to a .txt file and open it with notepad.
The problem is when saving/copying it via code, the text is not placed line by line, but in the same single line.

Comment: When you're in the debugger, does 'richTextBox1.Text' save and preserve the newlines?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
File.WriteAllLines(saveFileDialog1.FileName, richTextBox1.Lines);
```

Comment: You may be onto it. According to msdn, under 'Remark's for the RichTextBox.Text property; "To display multiple lines of text in a RichTextBox, set the Multiline property to true. To read or set the text of a multiline text box, use the Lines property."

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.text(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Oh!!! I think it would also work but I already solved the saving problem by using string arrays. Now I only need to fix the copying problem