# New line character in text file (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, text, io, carriage-return

I'm exporting text to a file in C# using `System.IO.File.AppendAllText`, and passing in the text file, and then the text I want to export with `\n` added to the end. When I view the text document, they are not on different lines, although that pesky return-line character is there between the lines. So the system may think it's two line, but a user sees it as one. How can this be fixed automatically without doing a find-replace every time I generate a file?

```
System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"./WarningsLog.txt", line + "\n");
```

Comment: How are you creating the text to append to the file? Are you using `StringBuilder` and `AppendLine()` or just concatenating a string?

Comment: Guessing what can be wrong in your code without seeing this code is not very effective.

Comment: Try add `\r\n` instead of `\n`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between "\n" and Environment.NewLine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015766/difference-between-n-and-environment-newline)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to use the `Environment.NewLine` instead of `\n`, because newline can be more than that. in windows (if I'm not mistaken), the default is actually `\r\n`

Although, using `\r\n`, will help you temporary, using `Environment.NewLine` is the proper way to go

Answer (score 6):

First off, there are [a couple of ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations) to represent the new line.
The most commonly used are:

- The **unix way** - to write the `\n` character. `\n` here represents the **n**ewline character.
- The **windows way** - to write the `\r\n` characters. `\r` here goes for the carriage **r**eturn character.

If you are writing something platform-independent, [`Environment.NewLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) will do the job for you and pick the correct character(s).

MSDN states it represents:

> A string containing "\r\n" for non-Unix platforms, or a string containing "\n" for Unix platforms.

Also, in some cases you may want to use [`System.IO.File.AppendAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383691%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes an `IEnumerable<string>` as the lines collection and appends it to the file. It uses `Environment.NewLine` inside.

Answer (score 0):

You could try building this with some file specific characters checks , like
new line, tab , etc....
Here is an example code which checks for new line and tabs :

```
 public static string Replace()
        {  
             string rLower =   words.ToLower().Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<replaced_newLine>");
            rLower = rLower.Replace("\t", "<replaced_Tabulation>");
            return rLower;
        }
```

Of course you might have a lot of different combinations , where an item that needs to be changed is followed by " " or "\n" or "\r\n" or "\t"