# StreamWriter: How to add a new line?

Tags: c#, file-io

I want to write a string into a file. My problem is that I cannot add new lines into the file.

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(String.Format("{0}.txt", svDialog.FileName)))
            {
                writer.Write(String.Format("{0}\n\n{1}", this.currentRealWorldObj.Title, this.currentRealWorldObj.Description));
            }
```

As you can see I am adding to 2 new lines ("\n\n") in the String.Format method. But when I open the lines are not added. How they can be added?

Comment: try `File.WriteAllText(fileName, textToWrite);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe platform issues? Look at [Difference between "\n" and Environment.NewLine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015766/difference-between-n-and-environment-newline)
Try Environment.NewLine

```
writer.Write(String.Format("{0}{2}{2}{1}", this.currentRealWorldObj.Title, this.currentRealWorldObj.Description,Environment.NewLine));
```

Answer (score 8):

There is a specific [WriteLine](http://TextWriter.WriteLine) function for this.

For example:

```
writer.WriteLine(this.currentRealWorldObj.Title);
writer.WriteLine();
writer.WriteLine();
writer.WriteLine(this.currentRealWorldObj.Description);
```