# How do I get this message box to properly put each sentence on their own line with C#?

Tags: c#

```
        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("In order to bet 'High' press the 'ALT' Key and the 'H' key at the same time." + "In order to bet 'Low' press the 'ALT' Key and the 'L' key at the same time." + "In order to reduce the bet's value in half  press the 'ALT' Key and the 'H' key at the same time.");
    }
```

This is what it looks like now.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using \n characters for each newline.

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(
    "In order to bet 'High' press the 'ALT' Key and the 'H' key at the same time.\n" + 
    "In order to bet 'Low' press the 'ALT' Key and the 'L' key at the same time.\n" + 
    "In order to reduce the bet's value in half  press the 'ALT' Key and the 'H' key at the same time.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 {MessageBox.Show("In order to bet 'High' press the 'ALT' Key and the 'H' key at the same time." + Environment.NewLine 
  + "In order to bet 'Low' press the 'ALT' Key and the 'L' key at the same time." + Environment.NewLine 
  + "In order to reduce the bet's value in half  press the 'ALT' Key and the 'H' key at the same time."); }
```

Comment: why not just '\n' wherever a new line is needed?

Comment: its the same and its not the same... Its a Platform question ... Environment.Newline work on all environment (Unix or Windows). Read that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015766/difference-between-n-and-environment-newline

Comment: ah cool, thanks for the link!

Comment: @Esperento57 Actually, there is a difference on `MessageBox`. See, when copying the message box into to clipboard (using Ctrl+C; a rather obscure but very neat feature), it will specifically replace all `\n` characters in the text with the full `Environment.NewLine`. This seems like a very clear platform independence decision. But if you start with putting platform dependent breaks in the original text, this messes up. On Windows, this causes all resulting line breaks to be `\r\r\n` instead of `\r\n`.

Answer (score 1):

you can to this too:

```
        List<string> ListMessage = new List<string>();
        ListMessage.Add("In order to bet 'High' press the 'ALT' Key and the 'H' key at the same time.");
        ListMessage.Add("In order to bet 'Low' press the 'ALT' Key and the 'L' key at the same time.");
        ListMessage.Add("In order to reduce the bet's value in half  press the 'ALT' Key and the 'H' key at the same time.");

        //Solution 1
        MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, ListMessage));

        //Solution 2 => Add using System.Linq
        MessageBox.Show(ListMessage.Aggregate((x, y) => x + Environment.NewLine + y));
```