# How to display text in message box on different lines?

Tags: c#

I want each Total displayed on a different line in the box but at the moment it keep overlapping. 
Could someone please show me the way?

```
    private void SummaryButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TotalMoniesTaken = AmountDue + TotalMoniesTaken;
        TotalGuests = NumberOfGuests + TotalGuests;
        TotalLunchBookings = NumberOfGuests + TotalLunchBookings;
        TotalEarlyBookings = NumberOfGuests + TotalEarlyBookings;
        TotalLateBookings = NumberOfGuests + TotalLateBookings;
        TotalCornerTables = NumberOfGuests + TotalCornerTables;
        TotalWaiters = NumberOfGuests + TotalWaiters;

        MessageBox.Show("Total Monies Taken is €" + TotalMoniesTaken + 
                        "Total Number of Bookings = " + TotalGuests + 
                        "Total Lunch Bookings = " + TotalLunchBookings + 
                        "Total Early Bookings = " + TotalEarlyBookings +
                        "Total Late Bookings = " + TotalLateBookings + 
                        "Total Corner Tables = " + TotalCornerTables +
                        "Total Waiters = " + TotalWaiters);






    }
```

Comment: [Put a `\n`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015766/difference-between-n-and-environment-newline) in there?

Answer (score 4):

Displaying this doesn't include a new line:

```
"Total Monies Taken is €" + TotalMoniesTaken
```

But this does:

```
"Total Monies Taken is €" + TotalMoniesTaken + Environment.NewLine
```

Answer (score 0):

Add newlines to each one :

```
"Total Monies Taken is €" + TotalMoniesTaken + Environment.NewLine
"Total Number of Bookings = " + TotalGuests + Environment.NewLine
```

..etc

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways that you can do this in C#, firstly you can use newlines in your string

```
MessageBox.Show("Total Monies Taken is €" + TotalMoniesTaken + 
                    "\nTotal Number of Bookings = " + TotalGuests + 
                    "\nTotal Lunch Bookings = " + TotalLunchBookings + 
                    "\nTotal Early Bookings = " + TotalEarlyBookings +
                    "\nTotal Late Bookings = " + TotalLateBookings + 
                    "\nTotal Corner Tables = " + TotalCornerTables +
                    "\nTotal Waiters = " + TotalWaiters);
```

Alternatively, you could use `Environment.NewLine`

```
MessageBox.Show("Total Monies Taken is €" + TotalMoniesTaken + Environment.NewLine + 
                    "Total Number of Bookings = " + TotalGuests + Environment.NewLine + 
                    "Total Lunch Bookings = " + TotalLunchBookings + Environment.NewLine + 
                    "Total Early Bookings = " + TotalEarlyBookings + Environment.NewLine + 
                    "Total Late Bookings = " + TotalLateBookings + Environment.NewLine + 
                    "Total Corner Tables = " + TotalCornerTables + Environment.NewLine +
                    "Total Waiters = " + TotalWaiters);
```

Answer (score 0):

just use \n at the end of each line

```
MessageBox.Show("test1 \n test2 \n test3");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do two ways:

1st one with \n:

```
Eg: string msg = "text\nwith two lines";
```

2nd way with Environment.NewLine:

```
Eg:string msg = "Text " + Environment.NewLine + "with two lines";
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the newer C# features (not tested)

    `MessageBox.Show(
    $@"Total Monies Taken is €{TotalMoniesTaken}
Total Number of Bookings = {TotalGuests}
...");`