# MapAreaAttributes calling javascript:alert function with newline character not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, charts, newline

I have a chart and I'm attempting to implement a javascript alert pop-up with information about the associated data point onmouseover.

```
Chart1.Series[0].Points[0].MapAreaAttributes = "onmouseover=\"javascript:alert('" message + "');\"";
```

where I have message defined:

```
string message = String.Format("{0} = {1}{2}{3} = {4}", "X", "#VALX", @"\n", "Y", "#VALY" ;
```

The issue I'm facing is I'm getting a SCRIPT1015: Unterminated string constant. I know it has to do with me trying to insert the new line character `@"\n"` because when my message doesn't have the newline character it works correctly.

Two possible solutions I've come across are to use `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode` or to use String.Replace(). I've tried fiddling with both but have had no success.

Comment: Have you tried [`Environment.NewLine`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015766/difference-between-n-and-environment-newline) instead of `\n`?

Comment: Yeah I have but to no avail either.