# 2 lines in the Debug.Log result C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, debugging, newline

How can I show the Debug.Log in 2 lines (like adding an `enter` or `<br>`) in C#?

I have lots of info to show and compare, yet it is not convenient to read it in one line.

**Current result:** `Debug.Log("Pointer:" + " " + pointerPosX + " " + pointerPosY + " " + "target" + " " + targetPosX + " " + targetPosY);`

**Expected result:**

Pointer: `pointerPosX + " " + pointerPosY`

Target: `targetPosX " " " + targetPosY`

P.S. This is my first question in StackOverflow - so, please, let me know if I did something wrong.

Comment: Are you searching for `\n`? You can also write two separate Log-Statements.

Comment: Try [`Environment.NewLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline) (related question: [Difference between "\n" and Environment.NewLine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1015766/3367974))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1 (`\n`):

```
Debug.Log("Pointer:" + " " + pointerPosX + " "
    + pointerPosY + "\n" + "Target:" + " " + targetPosX + " " + targetPosY);
```

Option 2 ([`System.Environment.NewLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline)):

```
Debug.Log("Pointer:" + " " + pointerPosX + " " + pointerPosY + 
System.Environment.NewLine + "Target:" + " " + targetPosX + " " + targetPosY);
```

Using [$ - string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

Option 1:

```
Debug.Log($"Pointer: {pointerPosX} {pointerPosY}\nTarget: {targetPosX} {targetPosY}");
```

Option 2:

```
Debug.Log($"Pointer: {pointerPosX} {pointerPosY}{System.Environment.NewLine}Target: {targetPosX} {targetPosY}");
```

[Difference between "\n" and Environment.NewLine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1015766/3367974)

Comment: Thank you, man! Was looking for this for a while!

Comment: @Mr.Schtelbe you can mark my post as the answer in order to help other readers, this is how StackOverflow works.

Comment: Mehdi Dehghani
 thank you, noted and done! P.S. No idea why, but I cannot tag you

Comment: You're welcome and thank you! (you can not tag me because only you and I are in this conversation/comment section.)